# illegal character in input string not working in javascript. how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, contenttype

I wrote a code to alert the "d@fdsf.fgfdg" like below code :

```
<button onclick="myfunction('d@fdsf.fgfdg')">clicks</button>
<script charset="UTF-16">
function myfunction(str)
{
    alert(str);   
}
</script>
```

But it alerted the result like `????????????????????d@fdsf.fgfdg`
Also in source its looking like below:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the image link format

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your file with unicode encoding then try it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try if this work?

```html
   <button onclick="myfunction()">clicks</button>
<script charset="UTF-16">
function myfunction(str)
{
var str  = 'd@fdsf.fgfdg' ; 

    alert(str);   
}
</script>
```